# 'bytesize' in PySerial module

Tags: python, size, byte, pyserial

I want to send messages through the serial port using PySerial. One of the parameters for the serial constructor is 'bytesize'. I have been trying serial.SEVENBITS and serial.EIGHTBITS and haven't noticed a difference. The documentation is a bit vague and I am new to both Python and serial communication.
Does this just set the maximum value a byte can hold or is it something to do with signed bytes? Can anyone clear up why I'd use 7 bits over 8?
I have been searching but haven't found an answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to the number of data bits in each transmitted character.  From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Data_bits):

> Data bits
>
> The number of data bits in each
>   character can be 5 (for Baudot code),
>   6 (rarely used), 7 (for true ASCII), 8
>   (for any kind of data, as this matches
>   the size of a byte), or 9 (rarely
>   used). 8 data bits are almost
>   universally used in newer
>   applications. 5 or 7 bits generally
>   only make sense with older equipment
>   such as teleprinters.
>
> Most serial communications designs
>   send the data bits within each byte
>   LSB (Least Significant Bit) first.
>   This standard is also referred to as
>   "little endian". Also possible, but
>   rarely used, is "big endian" or MSB
>   (Most Significant Bit) first serial
>   communications. (See Endianness for
>   more about bit ordering.) The order of
>   bits is not usually configurable, but
>   data can be byte-swapped only before
>   sending.

Comment: Re "Most serial communications designs send the data bits within each byte LSB"  Most serial hardware interfaces the poster is likely to encounter with pyserial abstract bit ordering away, providing only a byte interface. On the other hand, LSB Standards [UART (includes RS-232) ] but MSB Standards [SPI, I2C]

Comment: @Jack, you should go with whatever the thing you're interfacing with requires (generally 8, as noted).  If you're in control of both ends, then again you would have little reason to use 7 bits unless you had an (unlikely) combination of requirements involving ASCII-only data, and performance needs such that skipping the overhead of the redundant 8th bit would be critical to you.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, it was common to only send ASCII text over a serial connection, which fit into seven bits, and an eighth bit would be used as a parity marker which could indicate if the data was being transmitted correctly.

Since the parity check doesn't catch errors on an even number of bits, and can't correct the data at all, it's not that valuable, and modern practice is to use 8-bit data and do error detection and correction at a higher layer of protocol.

Short answer is you probably want 8-bit, but it depends on what the other end of the serial connection is expecting.

Update: 
From your other question it sounds like you're programming both ends of the connection, and checksumming your messages, so it's definitely most straightforward to use 8-bit.

Comment: Thanks Russell, very much appreciated :)